# Vue.js 2 Confusion about data load

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am kind of new on Vue. I am working on a Vue.js 2.x app where I have the usual Vue Instance with all the methods, data and other properties.

For instance, I have the in the data the following properties:

```
data: {
   users: []
}
```

In the `/admin` page I use Vue to load only five users with a method `loadUsers(5)`. Where in the **created** hook I call `this.users = this.loadUsers(5);`.

But in the `/users` page I load all the users within the same *users* variable. Right?

> I am using a PHP framework's router, not Vue Router.

How should I separate different data for different pages?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you need to be declaring `data` as a function. `data () { return { users: [] } }` like that. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Comment: I forgot to tell that I was reading about components. So.. I should use components, right? I'll read more in that URL.. thank you.

Comment: Yeah, perfect, I was writing up an answer on components. I put several links in for you.

Comment: That was the solution I was trying to find. I didn't find them before. Therefore I was writing the "thank you" but I can do it here... Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create separate [Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) per page. They come in several different varieties, [Single File](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), [Local](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Local-Registration), and [inline](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Inline-Templates).

I frequently opt for single file myself. I like the separation and organization they come with. As you get further along look into [Dynamic](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components). These are good swapping in and out a section of the page, but you're not limited by means.